# Scala pattern matching referencing

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

When pattern matching case classes how do you actually refer to the class which it was matched to?

Here's an example to show what I mean:

```
sealed trait Value
case class A(n: Int) extends Value

v match {
  case A(x) =>
   doSomething(A);
}
```

Where `v` is of type value and `doSomething` takes an parameter of type `A`, not `Value`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do this

```
v match {
   case a @ A(x) =>
   doSomething(a)
}
```

`@` is called [Pattern Binder](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (Refer § 8.1.3). From the reference:

> A pattern binder x@p consists of a pattern variable x and a pattern p.
>   The type of the variable x is the static type T of the pattern p. This
>   pattern matches any value v matched by the pattern p, provided the
>   run-time type of v is also an instance of T , and it binds the
>   variable name to that value.

Answer (score 1):

```
v match {
  a @ case A(x) =>
    doSomething(a)
}
```

By the way, you don't need the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Case classes are deconstructed

You wouldn't refer to A, as you would refer to the deconstructed object,
hence you would only get access to x in the context of your case.

However, you would know that the context was A, since you matched the case, so it would be easy to construct a new case class from your arguments.