# Extracting both tuple & individual values in list using pattern matching

Tags: scala, tuples

Here is my code

```
@ val lst = List((12, "aug", 2016), (13, "jun", 2016))
lst: List[(Int, String, Int)] = List((12, "aug", 2016), (13, "jun", 2016))

@ lst.foreach {
    case (day, month, year) =>
      println(s"Tpl is ($day, $month, $year)")
  }
Tpl is (12, aug, 2016)
Tpl is (13, jun, 2016)
```

As you can see I am able to extract the tuple into `day`, `month` & `year`. But the issue for me is when I want to print the tuple, I need to concatenate the values. Is there is a way to extract the complete tuple also (along with values) using pattern matching. I would need something like this(of course this **do not work**)

```
val lst = List((12, "aug", 2016), (13, "jun", 2016))
lst.foreach {
  case tpl: (day, month, year) =>
    println(s"Tpl is ($tpl)")
}
```

I know it is possible to do like this(shown below) ; but I am trying to avoid additional code & additional levels of indentation

```
@ val lst = List((12, "aug", 2016), (13, "jun", 2016))
lst: List[(Int, String, Int)] = List((12, "aug", 2016), (13, "jun", 2016))

@ lst.foreach { tpl =>
    tpl match {
      case (day, month, year) =>
        println(s"Tpl is $tpl")
    }
  }
Tpl is (12,aug,2016)
Tpl is (13,jun,2016)
```

Comment: How ironic that you are using `@` as a prompt (?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala pattern matching referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521637/scala-pattern-matching-referencing)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin  http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This answer is a duplicate of another answer:
>   [Scala pattern matching referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21521684/2707792)

Replace `:` by `@`:

```
case tpl @ (day, month, year) =>
  println(s"Tpl is $tpl = ($day, $month, $year)")
```

That's called [*pattern binder* (link to specification)](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html).

Comment: Not sure, should it be deleted or left as signpost?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of accessing the fields of the tuple, to Andreys code, which doesn't really show it, would be:

```
lst.foreach {case tpl => println (s"Tupel ${tpl} is ${tpl._1} ${tpl._2} ${tpl._3}")}
Tupel (12,aug,2016) is 12 aug 2016
Tupel (13,jun,2016) is 13 jun 2016
```

Comment: does not work ; try this val lst = List((12, "aug", 2016), (13, "jun", 2016))
lst.foreach {
        case tpl: (day, month, year) =>
          println(s"Tpl is (${tpl} -> $day, $month, $year)")
      }

Comment: It "works", but it matches three *types*, not *values*. Sorry, but you are missing the point entirely, and the names of the variables in your code suggest something that is wrong. Maybe you could make this post more helpful if you refresh [pattern matching](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns) and explain why the syntax works, even though it doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: Raj wrote "println(s"Tpl is ($tpl)")" wouldn't work, but it works. Now  "println(s"Tpl is (${tpl} -> $day, $month, $year)") }" for me looks as another question.

Comment: @userunknown As I said, it "compiles", but it does't "work", in the sense: the `day`, `month`, `year` variables are bound to crazy stuff that cannot be used inside string interpolations. As I said, I think you should really explain in more detail what the variables `day`, `month` and `year` are doing in your code. They definitely aren't doing what the OP expected: and the OP expected to be able to use those variables in a string interpolation. This is implied by the two paragraphs immediately before and after the code snippet you quoted.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: Since he accepted your answer, it seems as if you really understood his question. You don't do anything with day/month/year so I don't see what is working in your code.

Comment: I don't *do* anything with `day`, `month`, `year`, but I *could*, and it would behave as the OP expected. Whereas in your code, all you could do with `day`, `month` and `year` is: `val lst = List((12, "aug", 2016), (13, "jun", 2016));
lst.foreach { 
  case tpl: (day, month, year) => {
    val d: day = tpl._1;
    val m: month = tpl._2;
    val y = tpl._3.asInstanceOf[year];
    println(s"Tpl is (${tpl}")
  }
}` That's extremely counter-intuitive at first glance, and not at all what the OP wanted.